# Main advantages/disadvantages of coherance and ehcache as RI of Jcache API

Tags: java, ehcache, oracle-coherence, jcache

It will be good if some one can describe the main adv. and disadv. of using **ehcache** and **oracle coherance** as RI of JCache API.
 Of course it could be done by learning each framework separatly.

But to see a whole picture from the top I think it can be usefull. And to understand, what is the main purpose of using cahce instad of collections in java as it also stores in memory.

Comment: Infinispan implements the JSR-107 (JCache) API as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true that it stores only in memory - caching solutions can offload data into persistent storage (disk/database).

Few of common features that make cache more rich than java collections:

- JTA transactions participation
- offloading into persistent storage (various policies when and what)
- automatic expiration
- listeners for cache events (sync/async)
- indexing (query values in the map) and fulltext search

Caches are also often combined with distributed grids, where you get:

- throughput scaling
- failover handling (grid keeps multiple copies of data)
- distributed computing (usually MapReduce-based, or distributed task executors)

Usually you can also manage the caches using JMX, CLI or web interface.